# Eloquent: where are queries executed

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Atm I am building a very specific solution for an existing application written in Laravel. The solution executes queries in c++ modifies data, does sorting and returns the results. This c++ program is loaded in via a PHP extension and serves a single method to handle this logic.
The method provided by the extension should be implemented in Laravel using Eloquent, I've been looking at the source code for ages to find the specific method(s) that execute the queries build with Eloquensts Builder.

**Where can I find the methods that actually perform the queries?**

Why c++? I hear you think. The queries should be executed on multiple schemas (and/or databases) over multiple threads for improved performance. Atm 100+ schemas are being used with each containing thousands of records per table.

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php, which implements whatever database type is selected. I think it uses PDO for the most part.

Comment: @aynber I've examined this class already. It seems like most methods of this class return an instance of Builder or return a value after the query is executed. It also has methods for adding scopes, attributes and relations.  

Another class I found `Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor.php` handles the finished queries. This is getting me on the right track I guess.

Comment: I'm still thinking: "why c++". Queries are executed on your database, so large tables and numerous schema's won't be slowed down by php, your database takes care of that.

Comment: @Jerodev For the most part, it's about sorting and merging multiple schemas at once to return very large datasets. PHP is simply to slow for these operations. I've benchmarked different solutions in different languages and c++ was by far the fastest. 4.5 seconds for selecting 750.000 records spread over 50 schemas, merging, sorting them and performing some calculations on those records. Whilst with eloquent I got an occasional PHP timeout. And why so many schemas? GDPR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting and testing I have found a solution to my problem. In the class `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` you can find a method called `runSelect()`. This method runs a select statement against the given connection and returns the selected rows as an array.

```
/**
 * Run the query as a "select" statement against the connection.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function runSelect()
{
    return $this->connection->select(
        $this->toSql(), $this->getBindings(), ! $this->useWritePdo
    );
}
```

What I did to test my implementation in c++ to run the selects, I mapped the return values of `$this->getBindings()` to a new array to do some necessary modifications to some strings and did a simple `str_replace_array` on the prepared statement to get the full query. Eventually the c++ program will execute the prepared statemend and not the parsed query.
The modified method to suit my case looks like this. This has been done quick and dirty for now to test if it is possible, but you get the idea. Works as a charm except for the `count()` method in eloquent.

```
/**
 * Run the query as a "select" statement against the connection.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function runSelect()
{
    $bindings = [];
    foreach ($this->getBindings() as $key => $value) {
        $bindings[] = $value; // Some other logic to manipulate strings will be added.
    }

    $query = str_replace_array('?', $bindings, $this->toSql());
    $schemas = ['schema1', 'schema2', 'schema3', 'schema4']; // Will be fetched from master DB.

    return runSelectCpp($schemas, $query);
}
```